# How to trigger an exception when accessing an invalid key from a map in Dart

Tags: exception, dart, flutter

I am decoding a JSON string using Dart/Flutter, and I want to make sure that the resulting `Map` has all the keys I expect.

```
    return MyRecord(
        id: jsonObj['id'],
        name: jsonObj['name'],
        description: jsonObj['description']
    );
```

I thought I would get an exception if I tried to access a key that doesn't exist in the map, but Dart silently returns `null` instead. I guess I could simply use something like

```
    if( !(jsonObj.containsKey('id') 
       && jsonObj.containsKey('name') 
       && jsonObj.containsKey('description')) )
          throw new ArgumentError('Invalid JSON for converting to MyRecord: $jsonObj');
```

But I'm hoping there's a more convenient way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Dart should implement something like `fetch` in Ruby, which raises a `KeyError` when the key is missing. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-fetch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Still not super convenient, but a possibility:

```
MyRecord(
  id: jsonObj['id'] ?? (throw ArgumentError("id is required")),
```

Comment: I actually think this seems like the best way to do it, although it's seems like there should be a less verbose way of making Dart throw an Exception when trying to access a non-existent key.

Comment: If you use this, how can you distinguish the case when the key is missing from the case when the key is present and its value is null?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on where you want to do the check, you could write something like this:

```
var requiredKeys = ['id', 'name', 'description'];
var isMissingKey = requiredKeys.any((requiredKey) => !jsonObj.containsKey(requiredKey);
```

You can even call `.any` directly on the `List` literal to make it a single line if you want.

If you need to know exactly which keys are missing (perhaps for an error message) you can use this:

```
var missingKeys = requiredKeys.where((requiredKey) => !jsonObj.containsKey(requiredKey));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've opted into [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety#enable-null-safety), you *could* use `jsonObj['id']!`

```dart
MyRecord(
  id: jsonObj['id']!,
```

It's not a great solution though..

- The [documentation](https://dart.dev/null-safety) itself recommends against using it for null checking:

  > Important: If you aren’t positive that a value is non-null, don’t use the ! operator.
- The exception doesn't make a lot of sense

  > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of nullError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of null

You can play with null-safety [here](https://nullsafety.dartpad.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

In Dart 3.0, you can use switch expressions to convert JSON type to your object.

As an example

```dart
factory MyRecord.fromJson(Map<String, Object> json) {
    return switch (json) {
      {
        'id': String id,
        'name': String name,
        'description': String description,
      } =>
        MyRecord(
          id: id,
          name: name,
          description: description,
        ),
      _ => throw ArgumentError(
          'Invalid JSON when converting to MyRecord.',
        ),
    };
  }
```

If you have values that are valid as null, simply make the type nullable.

```dart
factory MyRecord.fromJson(Map<String, Object> json) {
    return switch (json) {
      {
        'id': String id,
        'name': String name,
        'description': String description,
        'age': int? age,
      } =>
        MyRecord(
          id: id,
          name: name,
          description: description,
          age: age,
        ),
      _ => throw ArgumentError(
          'Invalid JSON when converting to MyRecord.',
        ),
    };
  }
```

If you want to learn more about patterns, I highly suggest watching this video from the official Flutter youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aLvlqD4QS7Y

Answer (score -2):

In addition to the other answers, I found another way to do this.

```
return MyRecord(
    id: jsonObj['id'] ?? Null,
    name: jsonObj['name'] ?? Null,
    description: jsonObj['description'] ?? Null
);
```

Not sure if there might be potential side effects depending on what types of fields you're trying to assign to, but so far it seems to be working for all that I've tried.

The benefit of this method is that it is less verbose than

```
return MyRecord(
    id: jsonObj['id'] ?? (throw ArgumentError("id is required"),
    name: jsonObj['name'] ?? (throw ArgumentError("nameis required"),
    description: jsonObj['description'] ?? (throw ArgumentError("description is required")
);
```

but the Exception is still triggered in the actual assignment code, minimizing the risk of forgetting to add/change field names in a separate check.

Comment: That seems like a very bad way to do it... the error you should be getting is something similar to `_TypeError (type '_Type' is not a subtype of type 'String')`, which means you're trying to assign a type definition to a variable that expects a `String`. You would get the exact same error message if you used `jsonObj['name'] ?? String` or the name of any other class -- even `jsonObj['name'] ?? MyRecord`. Intentionally assigning a bad value to force an exception seems like an anti-pattern that should be avoided.

Comment: Also, another thing you might consider is doing the checks inside the `MyRecord` constructor itself instead of outside, unless you don't have control over the `MyRecord` class for some reason.